# Como configurar en python utilizando django la cadena de conexion a microsoft sql server 2022?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, connection

Estoy tratando de utilizar Django con una BD SQL Server 2022. Esta es la configuración que tengo.
[image: pip list]
En settings.py:
`DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'mssql', 'NAME': 'impresoras', 'USER': 'DESKTOP\\Usuario1', 'PASSWORD': '123456', 'HOST': 'DESKTOP', 'PORT': '', 'OPTIONS':{ 'driver':'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',}, } }`
Servicios activos:
[image: services.msc]
[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]
[image: Mensaje de error al ejecutar el comando makemigrations]

Gracias por su ayuda. Saludos para todos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo ver este video, ya que tengo entendido que aun no tiene compatibilidad con el 22 y creo que llega hasta el SQL SERVER 2019 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZuUQ35fG5I&t=13s

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el contenido del enlace que proporcionas. Piénsalo: si alguien con un problema similar más adelante encuentra tu respuesta, y el enlace está caído, ¿cómo podrá comprobar que tu respuesta es útil? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin!

anexo:

1. configuración que me funciono.

   ```
   'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'mssql',
     'NAME': 'BD.AAA',
     'USER': 'sqlserver',
     'PASSWORD': 'BBB',
     'HOST': 'CCCC',
     'AUTOCOMMIT': 'False',
     'AUTOCOMMIT': 'no',          
    'OPTIONS':{
         'driver':'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
   ```
2. sitio a seguir para asegurar se tenga instalado las versiones correctas.

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django

3. sitio a revisar

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-sql-server-3rd-party-backend-for-django-v1-2/ba-p/3693278